# fail with lock-free fixedsize queue

Tags: d, cas, lock-free

I try to implement something like lock-free fixedsize queue in D language

```d
import core.atomic;
struct Chunk(T, uint N)
{
    T[N] data;
    shared uint count_;
    shared uint queueCounter;

    @property bool full() { return count_ == N; }

    void append(T value)
    {
        atomicOp!("+=")(queueCounter, 1);
        while(1)
        {
            uint c = count_;
            if(cas(&count_, c, c + 1))
            {
                data[c] = value;
                atomicOp!("-=")(queueCounter, 1);
                break;
            }
        }       
    }

    bool wait()
    {
        if(!full())
        {
            return false;
        }

        while(0 != queueCounter) {}

        return true;
    }
}
```

Call it like:

```d
import std.parallelism;

struct S
{
    bool dirty;
    int time;
    int[16] data;
}

int main(string[] argv)
{
    const uint N = 14343;

    Chunk!(S, N) ch;


    foreach(i; taskPool.parallel(std.range.iota(N), 10))
    {
        S item;
        item.time = i;
        ch.append(item);
    }
    while(!ch.wait()) {}

    // DONE

    return 0;
}
```

It works fine with `N == 14343`, but fails without any message with 14344 (value depends on `S.sizeof`).

Why is program fail?

Am I doing correct CAS append?

Is `chunk.data` fully accessible after the "DONE" string?

Comment: chunk.data should be accessible after DONE, as long as the function hasn't returned yet. Once the function returns though, the static arrays on the stack will be invalid and any slices into them point to garbage too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're running it on Windows, where the default stack size is 1 MB (at least according to [this article at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Your `S.sizeof` is probably 72, which gives no more than 14563 instances of `S` (there are also other things on the stack, hence your maximum `N` is slightly lower).

Placing a larger variable on the stack causes a stack overflow, which should occur as soon as main is called: `ch` is then assigned the value of `Chunk!(S, N).init` which causes a write outside stack bounds, hitting a guard page and consequently crashing the program with a segmentation fault (at least this is the result on Linux when `N` is large enough to overflow the default 8-megabyte stack), or, in Windows terminology, an access violation (I don't have a Windows box right now to verify it).

There are a few solutions:

1. Use smaller `N`.
2. Increase stack size (see the article linked above).
3. Allocate `data` on the heap.